# Formatting JSON data to a excel file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a json object which I get it from another service. 
I want this json data to be exported into excel file such the value of the attribute 'access' is appended as a new column and the column contains either true/false.
If two records have same attribute "details" and "project" and "access" attribute is different then the two records should be merged into a single record in excel with both the values of attribute containing true.

Ex: JSON Object

```
{"Approvals": 
 [
  {"details": 
    {"ID": "A", 
     "object": "person"}, 
  "access": "user", 
  "project": 
    {"ID": "Z", 
     "entityType": "domain"} 
  }, 
  {"details": 
    {"ID": "B", 
     "object": "person"},
  "access": "superuser", 
  "project": 
    {"ID": "Z", 
     "entityType": "domain"}
  }, 
  {"details": 
    {"ID": "A", 
     "object": "person"},
  "access": "superuser", 
  "project": 
    {"ID": "Z", 
     "entityType": "domain"} 
  }
 ]  
}
```

I want a excel file like this.

```
details/ID,details/object,user,superuser,project/ID,project/entityType
A         ,person        ,true,true     ,Z         ,domain
B         ,person        ,false,true    ,Z         ,domain
```

I thought of using send_file in rails to generate the excel file but I couldn't think of algorithm to merge the two records if value of the attribute "details" and "project" are sames.

I can format the data either in jquery or ruby so I am adding both these tags in the question.

Comment: You can't actually do anything *in* jQuery, because it's not a programming language. You can do something in JavaScript *using* jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

While there are some potential questions, this should get you started:

```
data = {"Approvals" =>
 [
  {"details" =>
    {"ID" => "A",
     "object" => "person"},
  "access" => "user",
  "project" =>
    {"ID" => "Z",
     "entityType" => "domain"}
  },
  {"details" =>
    {"ID" => "B",
     "object" => "person"},
  "access" => "superuser",
  "project" =>
    {"ID" => "Z",
     "entityType" => "domain"}
  },
  {"details" =>
    {"ID" => "A",
     "object" => "person"},
  "access" => "superuser",
  "project" =>
    {"ID" => "Z",
     "entityType" => "domain"}
  }
 ]
}



records = Hash.new do |hash, key|
  hash[key] = [false, false]
end

data['Approvals'].each do |record|
  detail_id = record['details']['ID']
  detail_object = record['details']['object']

  project_id = record['project']['ID']
  project_type = record['project']['entityType']

  key = [detail_id, detail_object, project_id, project_type]

  index = record['access'] == 'superuser' ? 1 : 0
  records[key][index] = true
end

records.each do |key, value|
  p [key[0], key[1], value[0], value[1], key[2], key[3]]
end
```

Assumptions:

- detail id, detail object and project id, project type form the key, that is for every combination of those values you need one row in the output.
- if no access specified, then false

You can look up the doc for ruby/csv on how to generate a CSV file (or string) and then send that to the browser using `send_data`

If it is possible to change the order of the columns (move the permission flags to the end) then you can generate each row with

```
records.each do |key, value|
  p key + value
end
```

instead.
Please note that the `p` just prints the row to the console, this is where you want to hook in to generate the CSV.